# How do I organize complex data in julia

Tags: julia

I decided to try julia a few days ago and tried to translate one of my python projects to julia. I understand that using the type system is crucial for good performance. However, I have something like this in python:

```
class Phonon(object):
    # it has an attribute called D which looks like
    # D = {'on_site': [D00, D11, D22, D33 ...], 'lead':{'l': [Dl00, Dl01, Dl11], 'r': [Dr00, Dr01, Dr11]},'couple': [D01, D12, D23 ...], 'lead_center':{'l': Dlcl, 'r': Dlcr}}
    # all D00, D11, D22 matrices are numpy arrays
```

If I translate this into julia, it would be:

```
type Phonon:
    D::Dict{ASCIIString, Any}
end
```

It seems that compiler cannot get much infomation about what `phonon`s are. So my question is: How do julia people organize their complex data?

Comment: how about use [composite type](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/types/?highlight=composite%20type#composite-types) and zip `D`?

Comment: I tried, but `D['onsite']` is still `Array{Any, 1}`. Then I have to define another  composite type. It sounds not good.

Comment: what does your numpy array look like?

Comment: @GnimucKey, all are square arrays of a fixed size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if i understood you properly, you may want something like this:

```
type PhononDict{T<:Number}
    on_site::Vector{Matrix{T}}
    lead::Dict{ASCIIString, Vector{Matrix{T}}}
    couple::Vector{Matrix{T}}
    lead_center::Dict{ASCIIString, Matrix{T}}
end
```

i assumed that the element type of your numpy array <: Number, you can adjust it to something like `T<:Union{Int64, Float64}` instead.

the key problem here is `lead::Dict`, so `D::Dict{ASCIIString, Any}`:

```
julia> typejoin(Array, Dict)
Any
```

i suggest to change `D` into a composite type and then you can pass more info to compiler. more information concerning [parametric types](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/types/?highlight=composite%20type#man-parametric-types).